# php and mariadb not working as it should

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I'm just trying to show something to the page whenever I get the right 'hwid', but no matter if the hwid is in the database or not, it still shows 0. Any help?

```
[...] 
else if($action == "dl")
{
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE hwid = '$hwid'");
    $cnt = $query->num_rows;

    if($cnt == 1)
    {
        $logged = 1;
    }
    else if ($cnt == 0)
    {
        $logged = 0;
    }       
    else
    {
        $logged = 0;
    }
    if ($logged == 1)
    {
        echo 'yep';
    } else {
        echo '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `mysqli`? Have you checked for [`mysqli_error`s](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: Any chance that there's MORE than 1 `$cnt` row found? ... you will still `echo 0` if this is the situation.